# Bookmarklet to embed YouTube page with parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, youtube, embed, bookmarklet

My current code extracts the video ID of a YouTube video and embeds it on its own page:

```
document.location = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + document.location.href.match(/[&?]v=([^&#]*)/i)[1]
```

I want to add code that adds the three YouTube parameters "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1" after the video ID so it becomes:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEOID]?modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needs to be added to the rest of your document.location assignment:

```
document.location = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + document.location.href.match(/[&?]v=([^&#]*)/i)[1] + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=1"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this before with "%20"s instead of spaces which Chrome didn't like.